# Post parameters to api body returns error 403

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a API which expects parameters from body in postman i get 200OK and have the result,but in .netcore i get error 403 forbidden,

```
 var openPaymentesRequest = new CreatePaymentInitiationRequest()
        {
            CreditorAccount = new CreatePaymentInitiationRequest.CreditorAccounts()
            {
                Iban= "SE1230000000000000000002",

            },
            CreditorName = "Merchant123",
            DebtorAccount = new CreatePaymentInitiationRequest.DebtorAccounts()
            {

                Iban= "SE1230000000000000000001"
            },
            InstructedAmount = new CreatePaymentInitiationRequest.InstructedAmounts()
            {
                Amount = "123.50",
                Currency = "SEK"
            }
            ,
            RemittanceInformationUnstructured = ""
        };
```

I serilize the object:

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(openPaymentesRequest);
```

I create a quesrystring:

```
  StringContent queryString = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

at the end i pass the query string but im not sure if im passing to body or not,hope you can help me

```
var responseString = await _httpClient.PostAsync("https://api.co", queryString);
```

the header im posting

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Token);
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Request-ID", guid.ToString());
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-BicFi", "ESSESESS");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PSU-IP-Address", "192.168.0.0");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PSU-User-Agent", "mozilla/4.0");
```

for the guid i generate it which is not important,its just a random number.

Comment: http 403 error is caused by unauthorized acces. if you use any api key, may be it is expired. it can cause this error.

Comment: Did you by any chance forget some request headers? Which headers do you have in Postman?

Comment: whats 401 then?Im passing a token@BarışCanYılmaz

Comment: Pls post the Api header

Comment: and where is the token in the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
var contentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(contentType);
```

and I would try  to remove since I don't know what it is for

```
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Request-ID", guid.ToString());
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-BicFi", "ESSESESS");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PSU-IP-Address", "192.168.0.0");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PSU-User-Agent", "mozilla/4.0");
```